# HTML Feature Detection and Universal React

Tags: html, reactjs, universal, polyfills, srcset

We have a universal React application sitting behind a CDN.

We want to serve up HTML with [srcset](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) images from the server, but need to handle the fact that IE will not support this HTML feature, ideally using feature detection.

As the site is served from a CDN, IE will get the same initial HTML as other browsers. When the page loads in the browser, we want to swap out these srcset image tags for some different HTML, but this means React will complain about a mismatch between the client side HTML and the already rendered server side HTML.

What's the best way to handle this?

e.g.

- ignore the warning, or specify it's ok somewhere?
- use a client side polyfill that happens after the page has loaded e.g. using componentDidMount? In this case, how do we handle subsequent renders of an unchanged component not rewrite this HTML on the client?
- use a cache key on the CDN for the user agent - but this would mean sniffing browser rather than using feature detection

Answer (score 2):

The best and most compliant way is to leave both attributes. My guess is that browser will use "src" as a fallback but use "srcset" if available.

No polyfills or strange manipulations needed here :)